# Looking to select values grouped by one column but create a hierarchy of the different columns to find "the best" column

Tags: sql

Mightn't make much sense but let's try.

I have a dataset that is quite large and I have a few "duplicates" in a column. Within that column, I want to group it but select the corresponding row that is the "best fit" based on the max/sum of other columns. Is this possible within SQL?

Input:

| Name | Transactions | Date | Apple # | Orange # |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 10 | today | 10 | 10 |
| John | 15 | Yesterday | 10 | 10 |
| Jack | 10 | Today | 5 | 5 |

Output I expect:

| Name | Transactions | Date | Apple # | Orange # | Total # |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 15 | Yesterday | 10 | 10 | 20 |
| Jack | 10 | Today | 5 | 5 | 10 |

The hierarchy would be, max(transactions), max(date) and then sum(Apple, Orange).
I want to do it then for every unique name.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `row_number()`.  The key is setting up the `order by` to reflect the conditions you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by transactions desc, date desc, apple + orange desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I;ll have a look at this tomorrow! I'll let you know. Thank you